# ASP.NET MVC and jQuery DateTimePicker : can't display it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and in one of my views, I have to implement two DateTime fields which could be filled with a DateTimePicker. Here are my fields :

```
@Html.EditorFor(s => s.StartApp, new { @id = "Start_App" })
```

And the second one :

```
@Html.EditorFor(s => s.EndApp, new { @id = "End_App" })
```

As you can see, I gave them an id to say that I want these fields as DateTimePicker. Here is what I'm doing in my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Start_App').datetimepicker({
        // Arguments for the date picker
        showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        gotoCurrent: true,

        // Arguments for the time picker    
        showSecond: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        stepHour: 2,
        stepMinute: 10,
        stepSecond: 10
    });

    $('#End_App').datetimepicker({
        // Arguments for the date picker
        showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        gotoCurrent: true,

        // Arguments for the time picker    
        showSecond: true,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        stepHour: 2,
        stepMinute: 10,
        stepSecond: 10
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that I only have a DatePicker and not a DateTimePicker and I clearly can't understand why. Here are the scripts I'm including :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker is not a standard JQueryUI functionallity
you will have to use a plugin like http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/